# How to replace cell content on text value?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I use DataGridView. It contents button in one column:

```
Button cellButton = new Button();
clicked.  Here I'm just storing the row index.
cellButton.Tag = e.RowIndex;
cellButton.Text = "Выдать код";
cellButton.Click += new EventHandler((s, seder) => {
   string result = lnkSynEvent_Click(s, e, id);
   dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = result;
   cellButton.Enabled = false;
   cellButton.Text = result;
});
```

How to replace button on text value here in function after click:

```
new EventHandler((s, seder) => { // Here });
```

I tried:

```
cellButton.Click += new EventHandler((s, seder) => {

      string result = lnkSynEvent_Click(s, e, id);

      dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
      dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = result;

});
```

Comment: At first your cell contains a button. When the button is clicked, the cell content should be replaced with a string of text? Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: You are right, correct

Comment: I tried to create instance of DataGrigCell and to set Value for that. It does not work

Comment: Making an instance of a `DataGridViewCell` is not specific enough. You have to create an instance of `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`.

Comment: Can you edit you answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly, this should help you get going:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        BindingList<dgvitem> itemsList = new BindingList<dgvitem>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeTheDGV();
            itemsList.Add(new dgvitem { JustaTextField = "aksldjf sadfjasifuqw adsfasf" });
            itemsList.Add(new dgvitem { JustaTextField = "qwerioqu aisdfnvmz, oaa" });
        }

        private void InitializeTheDGV()
        {
            dgv.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + 5, this.Location.Y + 5);
            dgv.DataSource = itemsList;
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);
            dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { HeaderText = "My col header", Name = "mycol1" });
            dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewButtonColumn() { HeaderText = "click in this column", Name = "mycol2" });
            dgv.Columns["mycol1"].DataPropertyName = "JustaTextField";
            dgv.CellContentClick += Dgv_CellContentClick;
        }

        private void Dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(sender is DataGridView))
            {
                return;
            }
            dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = "put some text in here";
        }
    }


    public class dgvitem
    {
        public string JustaTextField { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code: `dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = "put some text in here";`??

Comment: Of all that code snippet, yes, that is the part you want. You override the cell type with `dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();` then you put your new string value in the cell using `dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = "put some text in here";`.

Comment: The snippet works.Create a new solution, paste the code, debug and try it out. Simply saying `it doesn't work` is much too broad and does not contribute to me or anyone else helping.If it indeed does not work, then an error message is likely thrown or some sort of `not working` behavior could be described as part of your answer in which you tell me it does not work. Help me help you.If `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = "blah blah blah";` instead of `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = result;` works, then check on `string result = lnkSynEvent_Click(s, e, id);`